# How to Add Vue Component as an HTML Tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to using VueJS, and I'm working on a learning project right now. 
I have a component called "Draggable", and another one called "ModalPage". 
"ModalPage" is as follows:

[image]

The code for this page is below:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <button @click="propagate">Propagate</button>
    <h3>Vue Modals</h3>
    <ul id="list">

    </ul>
    <!-- <div v-html="template"></div> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from '@/components/Draggable.vue';

export default {
    name: 'ModelPage',
    components: {
        draggable,
    },
    data () {
        return {
            msg: 'Welcome to the Modal Popup Page',
            template: `<draggable></draggale>`,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        propagate () {
            // console.log("propagated")
            list.append(`<draggable></draggale>`)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I also have a component called "Draggable" and its code is as follows:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <VueDragResize :isActive="true" :w="200" :h="200" v-on:resizing="resize" v-on:dragging="resize">
            <h3>Hello World!</h3>
            <p>{{ top }} х {{ left }} </p>
            <p>{{ width }} х {{ height }}</p>
        </VueDragResize>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueDragResize from 'vue-drag-resize';

export default {
    name: 'app',
        components: {
            VueDragResize
        },
        data() {
            return {
                width: 0,
                height: 0,
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            resize(newRect) {
                this.width = newRect.width;
                this.height = newRect.height;
                this.top = newRect.top;
                this.left = newRect.left;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What i want to do is to be able to click the "Propagate" button on the page, and have a `<draggable></draggable>` html element appended to the page, as follows:

```
<ul id="list">
    <draggable></draggable> 
</ul>
```

I'm completely stumped with this. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) will do your job

**Updated**
You can use v-for as discussion:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <button @click="propagate">Propagate</button>
    <h3>Vue Modals</h3>
    <ul id="list">
       <draggable v-for="index in count" :key="index>
       </draggable> 
    </ul>
    <!-- <div v-html="template"></div> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from '@/components/Draggable.vue';

export default {
    name: 'ModelPage',
    components: {
        draggable,
    },
    data () {
        return {
            msg: 'Welcome to the Modal Popup Page',
            template: `<draggable></draggale>`,
            count: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        propagate () {
            // console.log("propagated")
            this.count++
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @ittus, this works for hiding and showing the draggable elements right. Would it be possible to append many draggable elements in the same was as appending to an array?

Comment: Thank you! this is just what I needed.

Comment: Glad to here that! Happy coding!